# BroadcastReceiver register and unregister not working in Android

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I use **BroadcastReceiver** and register it , this works well but when press back button , my app show force close , in onDestroy() I unregister it, but I have problem
here is my code

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

    net = new NetworkReceiver();
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list1);


    try {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION);
        //filter.addAction(ACTION2);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(net, filter);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.d(TAG, "" + e);
    }}


 @Override
public void onDestroy() {

    try {
        if (net!=null) {
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(net);
            net = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.d(TAG, "ActivityVideo - onStop unregisterReceiver:" + e);
        //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance()
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Here is my error :

```
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp, PID: 13875
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp.ThreeFragment$PostGetter$1.customLoadMoreDataFromApi(ThreeFragment.java:483)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp.ThreeFragment$PostGetter$1.onLoadMore(ThreeFragment.java:475)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp.EndlessScrollListener.onScroll(EndlessScrollListener.java:59)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1948)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.setOnScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1937)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp.ThreeFragment$PostGetter.onPostExecute(ThreeFragment.java:472)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-25 21:57:46.722 13875-13875/osclassapp.faosclass.com.osclassapp
```

This line is my problem , please hellp me

```
android.content.Intentandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, 
android.content.IntentFilter)' 
on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because getActivity() returns null when you invoke it in onCreateView(). When your fragment onCreateView is invoked it is not necessary that activity is already created.

> You can move below piece of code to onActivityCreated and your issue will be
>   resolved.

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(net, filter);
```

Comment: Did you override onActivityCreated and moved registerReceiver inside it?

Comment: Yes , my app has listview , to get data from net with 10 items received , after scroll down and finish 10 items , increment page and send page number to php server by post method , it works well but when finish item received from php , page number to be continue send data to server and logcat in php server show additional number of page , at this moment , press phone back button , show unfortunately force close , I'm sorry for the long explanation and basically question

Comment: 10 items , page 1 , next 10 items , page 2 , ... n items page n until php server send data

Comment: This is a separate issue then.  Your issue of getting exception while launching the activity is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

The activity is not yet prepared therefore its coming out null. Try to register when you are guaranteed to get a valid activity instance like `onActivityCreated()` or `onStart()`.